Vue child component not mounting during rendering
const componentData = {
      "label": "body",
      "category": "default",
      "children": [{
        "label": "Droppable Component",
        "category": "Custom Components",
        "children": [{
          "label": "Registration Page",
          "category": "Custom Components"
        }]
      }]
    };

I have a json tree like this, where the outer component has the inner component inside of it. I am fetching the components definitions from database using there labels here and each component is made in Vue3.
// Register each component dynamically
        data.forEach(component => {
          const scriptObj = JSON.parse(component.canvasDisplayScript);
          if (!scriptObj.methods) scriptObj.methods = {};
          const methods = Object.entries(scriptObj.methods).reduce((methodsAcc, [key, value]) => {
            methodsAcc[key] = eval(`(${value})`);
            return methodsAcc;
          }, {});

          const componentName = `dynamic-${component.label.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}`;
          componentDefinitions[component.label] = componentName;

          Vue.component(componentName, {
            ...scriptObj,
            data() {
              return scriptObj.data ? scriptObj.data() : {};
            },
            mounted() {
              console.log(`Component '${componentName}' mounted`);
              const styleTag = document.createElement('style');
              styleTag.innerHTML = component.canvasDisplayStyle;
              document.head.appendChild(styleTag);
            },
            methods,
            template: component.canvasDisplayTemplate
          });
        });

so the thing is when I run the registration and mounting process on the tree. Vue mounts the parent component and does not mount the child component. Because of which when it renders I can only see the parent and not the child in the html.
Is there any way or workaround this?

Not sure about the whole thing in itself, but check this one first. Considering this, might explain why your child component is not mounted as you expect it. Unfortunately, I am not sure what the rest of your code is doing but I would also be careful with DOM selectors/creators while working with Vue.

Please, provide a workable demo. This is specific to how it works and which data you have including scriptObj, needs to be debugged. Not something that can be solved on paper
